# How to proxy App over a reverse SSH-Tunnel (multiple hops)

Tags: ssh, proxy, tunneling

a question to SSH-tunneling. I am trying to proxy Firefox over a Pi, that is in a network behind a NAT. This Pi builds a reverse SSH tunnel to one of my servers, which works pretty well.
When proxying, I usually run 'ssh -N -D54321 -f user@host' and tell my Firefox to forward everything to port 54321, but this time I am overasked.

Is it possible to effectively chain SSH-tunnels, including a reverse SSH-tunnel? And if yes, what is the easiest and most effective way to do so? In short terms - how do I tunnel an application from my computer over a server to a reverse tunneld pi?
Thanks in advance!

(I'm using proxychains as a proxifier if this is relevant)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One very easy way to do it is to use a recent version of OpenSSH which supports the `-J` flag (or the `ProxyJump` configuration):

```
ssh -N -D54321 -f -J user@onehost,user@anotherhost,user@yetanotherhost user@finalhost
```

Comment: Thanks, that's it! In my case tho command I execute is: ssh -N -D54321 -f -J user@server user@localhost -p19998 - so without comma.